# I am unable to Choose secrets from linked keyvault to be included in this Azure DevOps variable group..select Option is grey out

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I am unable to Choose secrets from linked keyvault to be included to the Azure Devops variable group

I have service connection with has subscription level access SPN and I have a keyvault and grant keyvault secret officer role to SPN.
Issue: when i try to map the keyvault secret to Azure DevOps variable group , I can able to see all the secret from keyvualt but unable to select the secrets . the option is grey out.

I have recently change Permission model to “Azure role-based access control” instead of “Vault access policy”. will it cause this ?
Please help me here.[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [Link secrets from an Azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault), it notes that

> Key Vaults using Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC) are not supported.

If you want to use it in the Azure DevOps variable group, please don't use the “Azure role-based access control”.

Comment: Thank you for reply ..I think in recent update RBAC is supporting for key vault

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support, I got the root cause, My azure keyvualt screts are expired recently because of that select option is disable in devops libarary , once i have update expire date , i am able to select the secrets